# Principais algoritmos de ordenação?

Tags: c, algoritmo, classificação

Quais são os principais algoritmos de ordenação?

Se possível com exemplos na linguagem C.

Eu não sei quando devo usar um ou outro.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entender isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta é um pouco ampla e colocar o código deles seria demais, até porque seria apenas uma implementação.

O [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) é disparado o mais usado porque atende bem quase todas as situações. Outros podem ser melhores em determinadas situações.

A [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) tem uma ótima comparação deles.

Uma [forma visual](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) de entender o funcionamento deles. [Outro](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html).

Outras perguntas que podem ajudar:

- [Por que aprender algoritmos diferentes que resolvem o mesmo problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353853/101)
- [Existe algum algoritmo de ordenação que execute realmente em O(n)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/265964/101)
- [O que define um algoritmo de ordenação estável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188646/101)
- [Ordenação estável vs instável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325088/101)

Comment: Qual deles é mais rápido?

Comment: Se existisse isso, ninguém usaria outros. Cada caso é um caso.Mas deve existir um motivo pro QS ser o mais usado.