# Ordenar usando critérios de desempate

Tags: java, classificação, collection

Preciso ordenar uma lista de objetos com os seguintes critérios:

- Maior média dos níveis de proficiência em cada uma das
  competências técnicas exigidas para a tarefa;
- Se as médias forem iguais, desempatar pelo preço mais baixo (`valorPretendido`);
- Se os preços forem iguais, desempatar pela Proposta registrada mais cedo (`date`);

```
public class Candidatura{

    private Date date;
    private double valorPretendido;
    private float media;
    private int nrDias;
    private String txtApresentacao;
    private String txtMotivacao;
    int nrCandidaturas = 0;


    public Candidatura (Date dataCandidatura, double valorPretendido, float media, int nrDias, String txtApresentacao,String txtMotivacao) {
        this.setDate(dataCandidatura);
        this.setValorPretendido(valorPretendido);
        this.setMedia(media)
        this.setNrDias(nrDias);
        this.setTxtApresentacao(txtApresentacao);
        this.setTxtMotivacao(txtMotivacao);

        nrCandidaturas++;
}
```

Terei que fazer o `sort` várias vezes até só existir um objeto que consiga permanecer após todas as eliminações? É possível ordenar apenas uma vez para obter o "maior" elemento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, dá para fazer tudo em um único `sort`.

Se quiser fazer uma ordenação específica, você pode usar [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) passando um [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) como parâmetro.

A ideia do `Comparator` é prover uma forma de comparação customizada. Basta você implementar o [método `compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)), que recebe dois objetos `obj1` e `obj2` e retorna o seguinte:

- se `obj1` é "menor" que `obj2` (ou seja, se em uma ordenação `obj1` deve vir antes de `obj2`), retorna um número negativo
- se `obj1` é "maior" que `obj2` (ou seja, se em uma ordenação `obj1` deve vir depois de `obj2`), retorna um número positivo
- se tanto faz a ordem entre eles, retorna zero

Então dada uma lista de objetos, basta implementar um `Comparator` que siga as regras que você precisa:

```
List<Candidatura> list = new ArrayList<>();
// adiciona Candidaturas na lista

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Candidatura>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Candidatura c1, Candidatura c2) {
        int cmp = Double.compare(c2.getMedia(), c1.getMedia());
        if (cmp == 0) { // se as médias forem iguais, desempata pelo menor preço
            cmp = Double.compare(c1.getValorPretendido(), c2.getValorPretendido());
            if (cmp == 0) { // se os preços forem iguais, desempata pela menor data
                cmp = c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate());
            }
        }
        return cmp;
    }            
});

System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

Primeiro eu comparo as médias. Se elas forem iguais (e somente se forem iguais), eu comparo o preço. Se o preço for igual, eu comparo as datas.

Repare que para a média eu comparei `c2` com `c1`. Se eu invertesse a ordem, eles ficariam em ordem crescente, mas ao inverter, eles ficam em ordem descrescente. Isso quer dizer que as maiores médias ficarão no início da lista. Já para o preço e data, eu coloco `c1` primeiro, pois os menores valores devem ficar antes.

No final, o elemento que você quer estará na primeira posição (o que tem a maior média, e em caso de empate na média, o que tem o menor preço, e em caso de empate no preço e na média, o que tem a menor data). Lembrando ainda que se tiver empate na primeira posição (dois elementos com a mesma média, preço e data), será retornado o que aparece primeiro na lista (já que a ordenação é garantidamente [estável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188646/112052)).

---

## Para Java >= 8

A partir do Java 8 você também pode usar a sintaxe de *lambda*:

```
Collections.sort(list, (c1, c2) -> {
    int cmp = Double.compare(c2.getMedia(), c1.getMedia());
    if (cmp == 0) { // se as médias forem iguais, desempata pelo menor preço
        cmp = Double.compare(c1.getValorPretendido(), c2.getValorPretendido());
        if (cmp == 0) { // se os preços forem iguais, desempata pela menor data
            cmp = c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate());
        }
    }
    return cmp;
});
```

Ou ainda:

```
Comparator<Candidatura> comparator = Comparator
        // média, ordem decrescente
        .comparing(Candidatura::getMedia, Comparator.reverseOrder())
        // em caso de empate, compara pelo valor (ordem crescente)
        .thenComparing(Candidatura::getValorPretendido)
        // em caso de empate, compara pela data (ordem crescente)
        .thenComparing(Candidatura::getDate);
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era mesmo essa a minha duvida se era possivel fazer ou não. Muito obrigado