# Existe algum algoritmo de ordenação que execute realmente em O(n)?

Tags: algoritmo, classificação, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Se tal algoritmo existe, como é possível um algoritmo ordenar uma coleção de dados em tempo linear mesmo caindo no pior caso possível (invertido)?

Comment: Sim, mas não é um algoritmo comparativo. Ele não faz nem sequer uma comparação entre os elementos do conjunto. Algoritmos comparativos são limitadas a `o(n log n)` no pior caso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certamente existe, depende do cenário. Com os dados certos (mesmo no pior caso), com os recursos suficientes (memória ou processadores em paralelo, por exemplo) é possível sim. Se compensa é outra estória.

Porém dentro da normalidade que se encontra por aí, o melhor possível seria um O(n log n).

Existem algoritmos que possuem complexidade linear no melhor caso, que pode ser o caso onde já está tudo classificado como deveria. É possível no [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) em implementação específica. [Insertation sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) e [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) são outros conhecidos que conseguem.

O pior caso depende do algoritmo, tem caso que ser invertido pode facilmente ser O(n). Ou até O(n/2) em alguns casos.

Se trabalhar só com inteiros com o tamanho correto pode usar o [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Existem outros algoritmos que fazem [contagem para classificar os inteiros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) ([exemplo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting)). Quando o dado é informativo da sua grandeza é possível usá-lo sem fazer comparações.

Em alguns casos consegue com o [Pigeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort).

Comment: para mim não ficou claro como pode ser possível existir um algoritmo de ordenação com O(n). Se queremos ordernar um conjunto de n elementos, somente a operação básica de olhar todos os elementos será de O(n).

Comment: Quando pega algo classificado como se espera, você vai navegando e descobre que não precisa mudar nada, só varreu. è só para o melhor caso. Tem alguns algoritmos que desperdiçam enorme memória para garantir que poderia só copiar os dados que achar para o novo local que sempre terá espaço não importa onde tiver que colocar. Por isso eu disse que não compensa, mas existe.