# Ordenação estável vs instável

Tags: c, classes, algoritmo, classificação, quicksort

[O que define um algoritmo de ordenação estável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188646/o-que-define-um-algoritmo-de-ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1vel)

Nessa pergunta já foi falado um pouco sobre o que é ordenação estável e instável, porém ainda não percebo a vantagem de utilizar uma instável.

Em que casos podemos usar uma ordenação instável? É sempre preferível usar uma estável?

Dependendo da estrutura de dados que utilizemos é preciso ter cuidado com a ordenação instável?

---

> Um algoritmo de ordenação é considerado estável quando consegue preservar a ordem de registro de chaves iguais, em outras palavras se os registros aparecem na sequência ordenada na mesma ordem em que estão na sequência inicial.

---

Essa explicação não percebi, o que seria os registros? Ex:

```
int vec[5]={4,2,5,1,7};
```

Se eu quisesse ordenar esse vetor o que seria preservar a ordem dos registros?

Comment: Em uma ordenação estável, em caso de "empate" (2 elementos iguais), a ordem relativa entre eles não é alterada. No seu array `{4,2,5,1,7}` não faz diferença pq não tem elementos repetidos. Mas suponha que tenho usuários com nome e idade, e quero ordenar **somente pela idade**: `{(João,30),(Maria,25),(José,20),(Ana,25)}`- com um algoritmo estável, em casos de empate (Maria e Ana tem a mesma idade), a ordem entre elas é mantida, então o resultado seria `{(José,20),(Maria,25),(Ana,25),(João,30)}` - Maria estava antes de Ana no array original, e o algoritmo estável manteve esta ordem.

Comment: E creio que nesse caso "registros" signifique "elementos". No seu array, 4 é um registro, 2 é outro, etc. No meu exemplo, cada usuário é um registro. Por isso em um algoritmo estável "os registros (os elementos/números/usuários) aparecem na sequência ordenada na mesma ordem em que estão na sequência inicial", mas só em caso de empate, ou seja, quando há "registros de chaves iguais" (*chave* seria o valor que está sendo considerado na ordenação - no seu exemplo é o próprio número, no meu exemplo é a idade), então "registros de chaves iguais" são números iguais ou usuários com a mesma idade.

Comment: Eu essa definição sei, mas qual era o mal de trocar `Maria` e `Ana`, é isso que nao entendo, penso que não será algo grave.

Comment: Creio que isso já está explicado na resposta do Maniero abaixo e na pergunta que vc linkou. Em resumo, se a manter a ordem original é um requisito, use um algoritmo estável. Se tanto faz, escolha o que achar melhor. Não é questão de ser "mal"

Comment: @hkotsubo Sim, depois é que reparei que estava la explicado. Obrigado mais uma vez

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui eu vou pela [Navalha de Occam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor): se todas as soluções dão o mesmo resultado escolho a mais simples. Que pode ser a mais eficiente.

Em geral se você tem 2 "josé" e mais nada que os diferencie tanto faz quais deles entra primeiro depois de classificado e, portanto, tanto faz que algoritmo usar. Mas se a lista classificada que está sendo montada precisa considerar a ordem de entrada na lista então o algoritmo estável é obrigatório. Basicamente a pergunta que deve fazer é se a posição na listagem original faz parte do **desempate** ou não, se ele é uma informação importante precisa usar o algoritmo estável.

Todo algoritmo de classificação instável pode ser transformado em estável se modificar a chave de classificação adicionando manualmente a posição, desde que ela esteja disponível.

Como sempre, é uma questão de quais garantias você precisa e quais comprometimentos você aceita. Alguns algoritmos abrem mão de alguma eficiência para oferecer estabilidade. Mas isto não é garantido, dependendo da comparação o estável pode ter mais eficiência que o instável.

Não é que precise cuidado com determinada estrutura de dados, e sim cuidado com a necessidade desejada.

Por exemplo, uma tabela de espalhamento não tem posição clara, então não faz sentido requerer estabilidade se esta for a fonte.

Lembrando que só pode haver instabilidade em caso de empate. Se a estrutura garante ter chave única a estabilidade é garantida para qualquer algoritmo. Então o exemplo citado tanto faz se o algoritmo é estável ou não, afinal não existe empate em 2 elementos dele. Leia novamente a pergunta *linkada* porque ainda não entendeu o que é a estabilidade citada.

Particularmente prefiro o estável sempre que não faz diferença ou que ela não importa, mas é comum fazer alguma diferença.

Pode ser que no futuro você precise da ordem original, mesmo que não precise agora, aí teria que refazer a classificação no original, se estiver disponível.

Além disso algoritmos estáveis tendem ter mais previsibilidade de consumo de recursos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado, este assunto de ordenação parece ter muito que falar, eu por norma escolho sempre o mais facil de implementar e com bom desempenho, como disse não olho muito se é estável ou não, provavelmente terei de me informar mais sobre isto. Como todos os algoritmos de ordenação já estão feitos eu faço um `copy paste` e altero apenas o necessário, sendo bastante facil de implementar um `QuickSort` como por exemplo