# Qual é o benefício de um algoritmo de classificação ser estável?

Tags: algoritmo, classificação

Um algoritmo de classificação (*sorting*) é dito estável se ele mantém a ordem relativa dos elementos com chaves iguais.

Creio que minha pergunta é, qual o benefício de manter essa ordem relativa?

Alguém pode dar um exemplo?

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/808617/2241463)

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/188646/101 OU isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325088/101

Comment: As perguntas linkadas me ajudaram a entender uma coisa que nunca entendi direito sobre a estabilidade: que o que é preservado é a ordem dos elementos com chaves iguais em relação à ordem em que estavam na disposição inicial, e não uma ordem intrínseca do critério de classificação secundário. Porém, até onde vi nenhum exemplo do link chega a ser um exemplo de utilização que mostre um benefício, e sim exemplos inventados com vista à exemplificação por si.

Comment: Mas o benefício é só este, não tem nada demais.

Comment: Entendi. É que na pergunta original (em inglês, linkada acima) eles tentam dar exemplos concretos.

Comment: Só enfeitaram o exemplo, mas em essência é o mesmo, porque não tem o que inventar

Comment: Se a ordem relativa das chaves iguais for importante pra você, utilizar um algoritmo estável te garante previsibilidade no resultado. Acho que é só esse o benefício.

Comment: Também acho que é só esse, acho que o espírito da pergunta era conhecer uma situação (na medida do possível não-inventada) em que isso é posto em prática.

Comment: Tem um detalhe de ordenações estáveis que não vi sendo mencionado nas questões linkadas. Se você precisar ordenar por duas chaves, digamos K1 e K2, nessa ordem, porém não tem condição de fazer a verificação composta, você pode primeiro ordenar por K2 e, usando uma ordenação estável, então ordenar por K1.

Comment: Minha resposta não serviu? Acho melhor eu deletá-la, né?

Comment: @RHERWOLF Não atendeu totalmente mas ajuda, se eu fosse você não deletaria.

Comment: Em resumo, disse que ordenação estável economiza o preenchimento e a manipulação de um campo adicional para desempate que é necessário em algoritmos de ordenação instáveis para dar a estabilidade. Também dei um exemplo prático onde estabilidade pode ser necessária. Alguma dúvida em alguma parte?

Comment: Pensando melhor, o exemplo atende a minha dúvida. Vou aceitá-la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem casos onde um novo elemento numa estrutura tem mesmo valor de chave de ordenação que outro já existente e que é mais conveniente seja colocado logo depois dele, como em casos onde é mais justo quando o que vem primeiro é priorizado. Mas e se na hora da inserção a chave de ordenação não é conhecida ainda, somente mais tarde será determinada?

Pois é, alternativamente pode-se inserir os elementos no final, ou seja, em ordem de inserção na estrutura para só depois então aplicar uma ordenação pela chave desejada, mas ainda assim levando em conta como desempate essa ordem de inserção, da qual de fato a ordenação partiu. Para isso, existem duas opções.

(1) Adicionar a cada elemento um campo que é o índice de começo de ordenação para utilizá-lo como desempate.

(2) Usar um algoritmo estável, assim não precisando desse campo.

Um exemplo de problema que sugere uma ordenação com prioridade dos primeiros sobre os últimos numa estrutura é o ranqueamento de candidatos concorrentes a vagas. Se restar apenas uma vaga para dois candidatos de mesmo desempenho nos exames, é mais justo que seja dada ao que se antecipou na inscrição ou ao que demorou mais para se inscrever? Numa concorrência a um cargo normalmente se utilizam vários critérios de desempate, mas se as notas nas avaliações são todas iguais então no final das contas é mais justo que quem se inscreve primeiro tenha prioridade na recepção de vagas, correto?